# Best approach for a administration panel in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, administration, backend

I need to develop an administration panel for a web application written with Symfony. Generating a backend application seems to be the first option, but I think it introduces some complications.

The main purpose of this basic administration panel is just managing users and configuring values for multiple

```
<select>
    <option>...</option>
    <option>...</option>
    ...
</select>
```

within the application. The only restriction is that a regular user cannot access this area, but the model and CRUD actions should have the same behaviour as in frontend modules.

Is it worth to create a whole backend application in this case? Or should it be enough to block access by checking the user role?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same application is easier for simple administration tasks that use the same design and components as your frontend application.

Permissions can be easily set using configuration and you should be fine either way .

You could create a separate application and use an admin generator...

It really is up to you how much you want to separate those 2 parts of your website.